# Is it possible to view output of visual studio cordova project as a web app in browser?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I am using Visual Studio 2015 tools for Apache Cordova for mobile application development on Windows 7.
To build and run my app, I have to choose one solution platform and one target.
Is there any way to view the output on my browser just like a web app with no emulator?

When I press f5, the result will open in a browser in an emulator mode which I choose as system platform and target device. But I want to run my app like a web application, when you right click on index.html and select view in browser.
I look for a project setting or a ‘system platform’ and ‘target device’ value that work like that.

*PS:Selecting any windows solution platform and local machine target needs Windows 8 or higher and the build process is failed.*

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found for my problem:

I used the url of my output result with emulator: "http://localhost:4400/index.html?enableripple=cordova-3.0.0-NexusS"

and then removed the emulator settings in url: "http://localhost:4400/index.html".
Using this url will cause some popups asking some things. These are for 'cordova.js' script which is referenced in index.html file of cordova project. As we do not need this in browser, commenting the line `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` from index.html, no dialog will open any more and the project will compile so faster for initial design that do not need cordova.
Now I will use chrome mobile mode (f12-> phone icon) to see mobile view of my app.

Answer (score 1):

@A.M.
The answer depend on your expectations.

If you just want to view the page layout and test some of the associated Javascript, the answer is **YES**.

If you want to test the plugin libraries and associated JS, the answers is **NO**.

However, here are some items to be cautious with - either way.

1. When running your code on a device, you MUST wait for the
   'deviceready'. There are not ifs, ands, ors, or buts on this - you
   must wait.
2. You can emulate some of the plugins. This Summer some of HTML5 APIs have become available. If you want to write a shim, you can emulate some plugins with the HTML5 APIs, and use the Phonegap plugins on the mobile device. NOTE: some emulators now support HTML5 APIs.
3. Not all browsers are equal and not all webview libraries are equal. Cordova and Phonegap both use a *webview* library with their respective platforms. On Android, it is called *Webview*. On iOS, it is *WKWebview*. These libraries are finally starting to get some attention. So Google, Apple, Intel and others are all making competing libraries. *better for us* ;) One new library for Android is called crosswalk. Many developers like it, but it is bloated.

Best of Luck

Comment: as you said I want it want to view the page layout and the initial design. So if the answer is yes, what is the solution?

Comment: We the answer is above. In all three points. So, direct answer for you is #3. Just remember  ***Not all browsers are equal and not all webview libraries are equal.*** As such, load the webpage into your favorite browser. To get into *responsive or mobile mode* - On  Firefox, use `shift+ctrl+m`. On Google chrome, use`shift+ctrl+i`, and look for the icon that looks like a phone; you may need to click on it a few times. On Apple's Safari, I have no idea. I do not own an Apple. But `shift+cmd+m` makes the most sense. Let me know how it works. -Jesse

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know how I use chrome to see the mobile view of an application. But the question I have is how I bring the build result of my app to the browser without emulator. I edit my question to clarify what I want better.

Comment: If you are asking me how to do this with Visual Studio, I have no idea.